# How to check whether the input from textbox available in the XML file or not? But no result is shown from my code

Tags: c#, xml

This is the code I used.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLDatabase.xml");
        var NumberExist = doc.Descendants("Users")
                        .Any(x => (string)x.Element("ID") == txtId.Text);

        if (NumberExist)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number already exist");
        } 
    }
```

My Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
    <Users> 
        <User Name="aa" Occupation="dd" Date_Of_Birth="123456" NIC="123123" ID="79461" /> 
        <User Name="Ali Rasheed" Occupation="Student" Date_Of_Birth="111694" NIC="4550246607037" ID="12661" /> 
        <User Name="Asif Rasheed" Occupation="Civil Engineer" Date_Of_Birth="241190" NIC="4550346603073" ID="90939" /> 
    </Users>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the XML file there, don't leave it here in the comments. Comments are not the right place, especially because they don't support formatting.

Comment: @Fabio I'm new here. but anyways can you help?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't know C#. To be honest I was attracted by the title beginning with "Hello guys", which doesn't fit this site's format. So I opened the question and gave you a hint on how to avoid being downvoted (editing the title would have been my next suggestion). Luckily, another user has fixed all these problems for you, and now the post looks good. But I can't help you specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, there is no `ID` element in `Users`, It belongs to `User`.

**Second**, `ID` is not an `Element`, It's an `Attribute`.

Therefore, you should change your code like this:

```
var NumberExist = doc.Descendants("User")
                .Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("ID") == txtId.Text);
```

Comment: @Behman_Aries. I tried it right now and it worked thank you a lot mate!

Comment: @Ali I'm glad someone could help you. However, when an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted, by clicking on the green tick on its left. Please do it! On this site it's the best way to say "thank you".